# Find element by accessible role and name with Selenium (C#)

Tags: c#, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to find an element using its [accessibility name and role](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/articles/accessible-name/) using C# selenium?

See the spec for more details: https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1

The rationale is we have a react project with lots of unit tests that already target elements using [role/name based queries](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/byrole/) - it would be nice to re-use the roles/names rather than have to change the mark-up to add ids purely for selenium based acceptance tests. Is there a selenium equivalent to the `getByRole` queries from testing-library?

**Desired Example**

Component:

```
<button>Cancel</button>
```

Unit Test:

```
const cancelButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Cancel" })
```

Acceptance Test (how to do this?):

```
IWebElement cancelButton = driver.FindElement(By.???("button", "cancel"));
```

**Trying to avoid**

Component:

```
<button id="cancel-button">Cancel</button>
```

Unit Test:

```
const cancelButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Cancel" })
```

Acceptance Test:

```
IWebElement cancelButton = driver.FindElement(By.Id("cancel-button"));
```

Comment: Bunch of googling, can't see any examples in the docs https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/locators/ or anywhere else sadly

Comment: I honestly think this question is too broad. A good answer requires understanding a W3C spec and writing a good amount of code. It would be best if you understand the spec yourself, try writing the code, and then post smaller, more focused questions about your implementation of the spec.

Comment: Think we're going to just go down the route of adding ids - time constraints and all. The good argument was made that using ids can make the acceptance tests agnostic of some details, e.g.

`<input type="text"/>`
`<input type="number"/>`

Will have different roles (textarea and spinbutton iirc), so switching between the two would break an acceptance test that only looked for one of the roles, which is against the spirit of acceptance tests as our QA pointed out.

Still would be interested to see if anyone else has solved this problem though

Answer (score 2):

If you want a `button` element containing exactly the string `'Cancel'` (i.e. you want an exact match), run this

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath('//button[text()="Cancel"]'))
```

otherwise, if strings such as `'foo Cancel bar'` are accepted too, then run this

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath('//button[contains(text(), "Cancel")]'))
```

Comment: The question is bigger than simply finding something by text. The key is understanding accessibility roles and names. Finding something by text is one of the ways to find something by an accessibility role and name.